# Change facebook page tab name dynamically

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to change the name a user sees on a Facebook page tab depending on their locale?

Example: An english user visiting my page would see "Games" as the page tab name, and a spanish user would see "Juegos" on the same tab.

Comment: No it is not currently possible to translate the tab name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I've found is the "localize" option on the app, where you can add support for different languages. This way when a page installs your app they will get a different Tab name, description... depending on the page language.

But it seems that it's not possible to do exactly what I wanted.